# Difficulty connecting a contact form using PHP

Tags: php, email, contact-form

I've tried multiple different ways to set up a contact form and connect it to an email address using PHP. This is my first time using PHP, however I know I've written the .php form correctly.

Whenever I send the form, I get redirected to an "Error 405" page.

I've Googled for a few hours, and some websites give confusing instructions about downloading PHP (which I have tried about 5 times with no success), others say that VS Code on Mac should already be able to use PHP.

I'll leave my HTML and PHP forms below (I've tried two different PHP forms with no success).

It is implied that this should be a very easy process, simply connect the HTML to PHP via "action: mail.php" attribute in the form tag, and that should be everything. Yet I have scoured the internet and have had no luck so far... Any help would be appreciated!

(I'll leave the code below, first is HTML and second/third are the two different PHP forms I have tried).

The link to my Github is here as well: "https://github.com/cjmaret/abt-website"

```
<form class="contact-form__form-section" action="mail.php" method="POST" accept-charset="UTF-8">
                <h2 class="contact-form__form-section__title">Get In Touch</h2>
                <p class="contact-form__form-section__subtitle">Fill out the form or call ###-###-#### to request an
                    estimate or more information. We look forward to assisting you!</p>

                <fieldset class="fieldset">
                    <select class="input input_select" id="dropdown" name="dropdown" required>
                        <option value>Subject*</option>
                        <option value="accounts-receivable">Accounts Receievable</option>
                        <option value="accounts-payable">Accounts Payable</option>
                        <option value="human-resources">Human Resources</option>
                        <option value="quotes-estimates">Quotes/Estimates</option>
                        <option value="w9-certificates">W9/Certificates of Insurance</option>
                        <option value="careers">Careers</option>
                        <option value="general-feedback">General Feedback</option>
                        <option value="request-service">Request Service</option>
                    </select>

                    <div class="input">
                        <input class="text-input" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name*" required>
                    </div>

                    <div class="input">
                        <input class="text-input" type="text" name="company" placeholder="Company">
                    </div>

                    <div class="input">
                        <input class="text-input" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email*" required>
                    </div>

                    <div class="input">
                        <input class="text-input" type="tel" name="phone" placeholder="Phone">
                    </div>

                    <div class="input">
                        <textarea class="textarea" type="text" name="message" placeholder="How Can We Help?"></textarea>
                    </div>

                    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="#########################"></div>

                    <button type="submit" class="button-primary button-primary_place_contact-form">
                        <p class="button-primary__text button-primary__text_place_contact-form">Get Started</p>
                    </button>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
```

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['Email'])) {

    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "cjmaret@gmail.com";
    $email_subject = "New form submissions";

    function problem($error)
    {
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br><br>";
        echo $error . "<br><br>";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br><br>";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if (
        !isset($_POST['Name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['Email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['Message'])
    ) {
        problem('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');
    }

    $name = $_POST['Name']; // required
    $email = $_POST['Email']; // required
    $message = $_POST['Message']; // required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

    if (!preg_match($email_exp, $email)) {
        $error_message .= 'The Email address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br>';
    }

    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

    if (!preg_match($string_exp, $name)) {
        $error_message .= 'The Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br>';
    }

    if (strlen($message) < 2) {
        $error_message .= 'The Message you entered do not appear to be valid.<br>';
    }

    if (strlen($error_message) > 0) {
        problem($error_message);
    }

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string)
    {
        $bad = array("content-type", "bcc:", "to:", "cc:", "href");
        return str_replace($bad, "", $string);
    }

    $email_message .= "Name: " . clean_string($name) . "\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: " . clean_string($email) . "\n";
    $email_message .= "Message: " . clean_string($message) . "\n";

    // create email headers
    $headers = 'From: ' . $email . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: ' . $email . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
?>

    <!-- include your success message below -->

    Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.

<?php
}
?>
```

```
#!/usr/bin/php

<?php 
$name = $_POST['name'];
$company = $_POST['company'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$dropdown = $_POST['dropdown'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent="From: $name \n Phone: $phone \n Company: $company \n Email: $email \n Subject: $dropdown \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "cjmaret@gmail.com";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!";
?>
```

Comment: please check whether your server is capable of running PHP.

Comment: I am using the Live server extension from VS Code. I haven't hosted this website yet. Yet the Live server extension is displaying the 405 error